# How to cross-compile Boost libraries

Tags: c++, boost, cross-compiling

I'm trying to cross-compile the Boost library for an ARM platform (poky toolchain) and I'm new to cross compilation.  I'm having issues at the first step -- running bootstrap.sh.  I see many posts regarding boost cross-compilation, but not so many helping at the bootstrap level.

A few questions:

1) What should I put exactly in 'user-config.jam'?  I tried:

```
using gcc : arm : arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-g++ ;
```

I see many ones specifying an exact path to the compiler.

2) Where's the best place to put the user-config.jam file?  I tried my home (~) folder and the current folder.

3) The toolchain has a file named "environment-setup-cortexa9hf-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi", should I "source it" before running bootstrap?

Any help appreciated, thanks.

Comment: If you are using poky, why not just enable boost in yocto and rebuild toolchain, then boost is just included?

Comment: Another team has the control on the toolchain, but I'll try to have them rebuild it.  Thanks

Comment: recipes for boost is already included in yocto as far as I know, so you only need to include it into your rootfs target and toolchain target. if you have a team building yocto, they should know the how.

Answer (score 1):

Common tasks - 1.64.0
https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/bbv2/tasks.html

Cross-compilation
Boost.Build supports cross compilation with the gcc and msvc toolsets.

When using gcc, you first need to specify your cross compiler in user-config.jam (see the section called “Configuration”), for example:

```
using gcc : arm : arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ ;
```

After that, if the host and target os are the same, for example Linux, you can just request that this compiler version be used:

```
b2 toolset=gcc-arm
```

If you want to target a different operating system from the host, you need to additionally specify the value for the target-os feature, for example:

```
# On windows box
b2 toolset=gcc-arm target-os=linux
# On Linux box
b2 toolset=gcc-mingw target-os=windows
```

For the complete list of allowed opeating system names, please see the documentation for target-os feature.

When using the msvc compiler, it's only possible to cross-compile to a 64-bit system on a 32-bit host. Please see the section called “64-bit support” for details.